# A question on abelian Lie groups and maximal compact subgroup

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I need someone to review my following work:

Let $G$ be a connected abelian complex Lie group and let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G$. Let $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak k $ be the Lie algebras of $G$ and $K$ resp. such that $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak k+i\mathfrak k$.

(I am not sure about the following) We can write $\mathfrak g=(\mathfrak k+i\mathfrak k)/(\mathfrak k\cap i\mathfrak k)\oplus \mathfrak k\cap i\mathfrak k$. We also have,

- $(\mathfrak k+i\mathfrak k)/(\mathfrak k\cap i\mathfrak k)$ is totally real.
- We can write $G$ as a direct sum of two abelian complex Lie groups so that the Lie algebra of the first group is $(\mathfrak k+i\mathfrak k)/(\mathfrak k\cap i\mathfrak k)$ and the Lie algebra for the second group is $\mathfrak k\cap i\mathfrak k$.

Comment: If I'm not wrong: it's false; for example $G=\mathbb{C}^{\times},\,K=U(1),\,\mathfrak{g}=\mathbb{C},\,\mathfrak{u}(1)=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathfrak{u}(1)+i\mathfrak{u}(1)=\mathbb{C}$ which is not totally real.